# Как передать ссылку на объект, для которого производится валидация полей?

Tags: spring, hibernate, валидация, bean-validation

Сделал пару аннотаций для проверки уникланости email и username. При регистрации все отлично работает. Начал реализовывать профиль пользователя с возможностью исправлять email и пароль, думал проверку проведу с помощью тех же аннотаций, но тут наткнулся на проблему.

Когда проходит валидация email я через вызов userRepository.findByEmail ищу в базе пользователя с таким email и если такой присутствует валидация не проходит, т.е. email занят. Но на самом деле находится этот же самый пользователь.

Теперь думаю, как передать в Валидатор ссылку на объект у которого проверяется поле?

Привожу связанный с этим код.

entity:

```
@Data
@Table(name = "users")
@NoArgsConstructor
@CheckPasswordConfirm(message = "Пароль и подтверждение пароля не равны!")
@Entity
public class User implements UserDetails{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank(message = "Имя пользователя не может быть пустым!")
    @UniqueUsername(message = "Указанное имя пользователя занято!")
    private String username;

    @NotBlank(message = "Пароль не может быть пустым!")
    private String password;

    @Transient
    @NotBlank(message = "Подтверждение пароля не может быть пустым!")
    private String passwordconfirm;

    private boolean active;

    @Email(message = "E-mail введен не верно!")
    @NotBlank(message = "E-mail не может быть пустым!")
    @UniqueEmail(message = "Указанный e-mail уже используется!")
    private String email;

    private String activationCode;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_role", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> roles;

    public boolean isAdmin()
    {
        return roles.contains(Role.ADMIN);
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
        return getRoles();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled() {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Аннотация UniqueEmail:

```
@Constraint(validatedBy = UniqueEmailValidator.class)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.FIELD)
public @interface UniqueEmail {

    public String message();

    public Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    public Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default{};

}
```

Валидатор:

```
package ru.watchlist.domain.validation.validators;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import ru.watchlist.domain.validation.annotations.UniqueEmail;
import ru.watchlist.service.UserService;

public class UniqueEmailValidator implements ConstraintValidator<UniqueEmail, String> {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return value != null && !userService.isEmailAlredyUse(value);
    }

}
```

userService.isEmailAlredyUse:

```
    public boolean isEmailAlredyUse(String value) {
        User user = userRepository.findByEmail(value);
        if(user != null) {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Тут бы хорошо добавить условие на проверку того, что найденный user не равняется текущему. Как в этом случае передать ссылку на пользователя, поле Email которого проверяется? Или username пользователя?

Comment: может стоит перестроить аннотацию на класс? А полями аннотации сделать имена полей `user` и `email`. После в валидаторе рефлексией вытащить их значения из полей и уже делать по ним поиск?